# How to create a many-to-many relation with an intermediate table

Tags: objectbox

I want to create a many-to-many relation with an intermediate table with extra fields in this intermediate table, just like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2hYC.png

and I just made this mapping, can this work?

```
@Entity
public class Personagem {
    @Id
    private Long Id;

    @Index(type = IndexType.HASH)
    @Unique
    private String nome;

    private ToMany<Classe> classes;
```

Comment: If I interpret your diagram correctly, you want a `Classe_Personagem` class that has a `ToOne` to `Classe` and a `ToOne` to `Personagem`? You could then add a `@Backlink ToMany` to `Personagem` and `Classe`.
Anyhow see https://docs.objectbox.io/relations for details. Also note: standalone ToMany relations are one-way only.

Comment: Not exactly, i want a list of `Classe`  in `Personagem`, and many `Personagem` can have many `Classe`, but some `Classe`'s variables may be differents on each `Personagem` in a SQL database, I have to create this intermediate table(`Classe_Personagem`), but in the ObjectBox I thought I did not need to do this.
But if I do it that way, it will work correctly.